# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at localhost:5432 in GitHub Actions

Tags: postgresql, docker, github-actions, integration-testing, prisma

Currently I have CI/CD on my back-end project with Prisma through GitHub actions. The one part of it is integration tests. Before running the tests there is created a testing PostgreSQL database in GitHub actions, which is used for testing.

Unfortunately, **sometimes**, testing script fails with error:

```
Run npm run test:migrate

> fictadvisor-api@0.0.1 test:migrate
> dotenv -e .testing.env -- prisma migrate deploy

Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": PostgreSQL database "postgres", schema "public" at "localhost:5432"

Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at localhost:5432

Please make sure your database server is running at localhost:5432.
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I have bolded sometimes, because after 1-2 restarts everything is okay. Setting `connection_timeout` in the `DATABASE_URL` env has no effect.

Current GitHub actions steps for integration testing:

```
  integration-test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v3
      - name: Install Node and dependencies
        uses: ./.github/actions/install
      - name: Start PostgreSQL Database
        run: |
          docker-compose up -d
      - name: Start migration
        run: npm run test:migrate
      - name: Start generating
        run: npm run test:generate
      - name: Start seeding
        run: npm run test:seed
      - name: Run integration tests
        run: npm run test:integration
```

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: postgres:15
    container_name: testing-db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
```

The `package.json` scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "dotenv -e .development.env -- cross-env NODE_ENV=development nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .ts",
    "lint:fix": "eslint . --ext .ts --fix",
    "test:unit": "cross-env NODE_ENV=testing dotenv -e .testing.env -- jest -c jest.unit.config.json",
    "test:integration": "cross-env NODE_ENV=testing dotenv -e .testing.env -- jest -c jest.integration.config.json -i",
    "test:migrate": "dotenv -e .testing.env -- prisma migrate deploy",
    "test:seed": "dotenv -e .testing.env -- prisma db seed",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "test:generate": "dotenv -e .testing.env -- prisma generate",
    "integration:full": "docker compose up -d && yarn test:migrate && yarn test:seed && yarn test:integration && docker compose down",
    "generate:dev": "dotenv -e .development.env -- npx prisma generate",
    "migrate:sql": "dotenv -e .development.env -- npx prisma migrate dev --create-only --name",
    "migrate:dev": "dotenv -e .development.env -- npx prisma migrate dev"
  },
```

The `.testing.env`:

```
SECRET=testing-secret
DATABASE_URL=postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/postgres
TIME_DIFFERENCE=3
TZ=UTC
```

The package.json dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@nestjs-modules/mailer": "^1.8.1",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.3",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/schedule": "^3.0.1",
    "@nestjs/swagger": "^6.3.0",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.1",
    "@prisma/client": "4.16.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jsdom": "^21.1.0",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.7",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "axios": "^1.2.1",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.37.12",
    "dotenv-cli": "^7.2.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "jsdom": "^22.0.0",
    "nodemailer": "^6.9.0",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pizzip": "^3.1.4",
    "prisma": "4.16.2",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rimraf": "^5.0.1",
    "rxjs": "^7.6.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@nestjs/cli": "^9.1.5",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.3",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.2.1",
    "@types/cron": "^2.0.1",
    "@types/dateformat": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.15",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.1",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/node": "^20.2.5",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.59.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.59.7",
    "eslint": "^8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.5.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.26.0",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.1",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.1.0",
    "ts-loader": "^9.4.2",
    "ts-node": "10.9.1",
    "tsconfig-paths": "^4.1.1",
    "typescript": "5.0.4"
  }
```

Comment: You need to add some sleep time (delay) after starting PostgreSQL server (as you're starting `docker-compose` in daemon mode so it won't block). It may not be up and running by the time the tests are run e.g. `docker-compose up -d && sleep 30s`.

Comment: You can observe the startup time of PostgreSQL server and then adjust the delay accordingly to make it optimal.